# Problems with replacing "\" character

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem. i have text containing "\line" like Username \line Firstname \line. I want to replace this with \r\n. My code:

```
string _text = query;
_text.Replace("\Line", " \r\n");
```

It gives the following error: Unrecognized escape sequence.

Anyone wit a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use escape sequence, write it like that: _text.Replace("\\Line", " \r\n");         https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: `\L` is indeed unknown escape sequence, put `\\L` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash

```
_text.Replace("\\Line", " \r\n");
```

Alternatively you could try the string literal (haven't tried this though):

```
_text.Replace(@"\Line", " \r\n");
```